# Cutting a hole in an angled surface

Tags: modeling, mesh

Ok, so lets say I have a mesh like the one on the left, and I want to make a hole in it like the one on the right, as illustrated here:

[image]

but, using the methods I can think of, you end up with  inner vertices that are out of alignment with the outer edge, thus producing a non-flat surface as you can kind of see here:

[image]

also, as I just eyeballed it, the shape and curves of the hole are not totally symmetrical at each corner, so, what is the best way to cut a hole like this, with symmetrical measurements, in a surface that is at an angle, and keeping everything in perfect alignment with the surface itself without creating any n-gons and having clean topology?

Comment: Hit i in your keyboard to use the inset tool

Comment: Knife Project was made for cases like that. I suggest you read up on that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use boolean modyfier.

1. Create an object that has the shape of the hole you want to create.
   [image]
2. Add boolean modyfier to the object you want to cut a hole into.
   [image]
3. Make sure that the operation type was set to difference. Choose object that you want to use as holecutter.

[image]

4. Slide the holecutter into the place where you want hole to be.
   [image]
5. Apply the modyfier and remove the holecutter.
   [image]
   Hope you understood my bad english, but if this post helped then let me know by votng this answer up. Cheers! :)